# MVC 5 new project identity tables to sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, localdb

When I create a new mvc 5 project (individual user account authentication) I get the database in localDb. I need some other tables in my database to relate with user tables which will probably sit in sql (just because i never seen localDb used in production in any place that I worked so far), therefore I probably would want to have the user tables created in my sql server instance as well. I understand that **aspnet_regsql.exe** is not the tool to use for the new asp.net identity tables creation.

- So how do I get user tables to my sql server ?
- As well why does the new project always push towards localDb ?

Comment: Just change the connection string, they will be created for you when the application hits the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So how do I get user tables to my sql server ?

- Change the connection string to access your ms sql server. Entity Framework will create the tables automatically when you try to access the database in your application.

As well why does the new project always push towards localDb?

- This is done so you can quickly get up and running (it's not recommended for production use as it's not designed to work with IIS). You don't need any specific database installed for your application to work.